# change button style on Python 2.7.9

Tags: python-2.7

I have 4 Button on a circel and I want to change the button style to oval or to round in order to take all buttons into the circel! how can do that? thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you post your code so far? What GUI toolkit are you using?

Comment: I have posted myCode! I want to change the style of Button 1, 3, 7, and 9 because I have a round screen and I cant see the siedes of those button, therfoe I want to chage it! (Just one side for each button)

Comment: Are you using Tkinter? PyQt? wxPython? Kivy? ...

Answer (score -1):

```
from Tkinter import Tk, W, E
from ttk import Frame, Button, Label, Style
from ttk import Entry


class AllButtons(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):

        Frame.__init__(self, parent)   

        self.parent = parent

        self.initUI()

    def callback(self, number):
        print "click!", self, number

    def initUI(self):


        self.parent.title("mGUI")
        Style().configure("TButton", padding=(0, 5, 0, 5),
            font='serif 20', background="Black", foreground="red",
            activebackground="Green,",activeforeground="Green")

        self.columnconfigure(0, pad=3)
        self.columnconfigure(1, pad=3)
        self.columnconfigure(2, pad=3)
        self.columnconfigure(3, pad=3)

        self.rowconfigure(0, pad=3)
        self.rowconfigure(1, pad=3)
        self.rowconfigure(2, pad=3)
        self.rowconfigure(3, pad=3)
        self.rowconfigure(4, pad=3)



        Funk_1 = Button(self, text="Funk_1", command=lambda:self.callback(1))
        Funk_1.grid(row=1, column=0)

        Funk_2 = Button(self, text="Funk_2", command=lambda:self.callback(2))
        Funk_2.grid(row=1, column=1)

        Funk_3 = Button(self, text="Funk_3", command=lambda:self.callback(3))
        Funk_3.grid(row=1, column=3)        

        Funk_4 = Button(self, text="Funk_4", command=lambda:self.callback(4))
        Funk_4.grid(row=3, column=0)

        Funk_5 = Button(self, text="Funk_5", command=lambda:self.callback(5))
        Funk_5.grid(row=3, column=1)         

        Funk_6 = Button(self, text="Funk_6", command=lambda:self.callback(6))
        Funk_6.grid(row=3, column=3)            

        Funk_7 = Button(self, text="Funk_7", command=lambda:self.callback(7))
        Funk_7.grid(row=5, column=0)

        Funk_8 = Button(self, text="Funk_8", command=lambda:self.callback(8))
        Funk_8.grid(row=5, column=1)         

        Funk_9 = Button(self, text="Funk_9", command=lambda:self.callback(9))
        Funk_9.grid(row=5, column=3)

        self.pack()

def main():

    mGUI = Tk()
    app = AllButtons(mGUI)
    mGUI.mainloop()  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

Comment: This is not an answer. If you want to add more information to your question you can edit the question.